# Loop of bluescreen error caused by TDR failure

Tags: windows-10, boot, graphics-card, bsod, asus-laptop

I have an old ASUS notebook for about 10 years with the Graphics card model E2 1800 AMD. I installed Windows 10 about 6 month ago. Everything was perfect but now the windows does not boot and always goes to the blue screen and the repair could not fix the issue. The error is of the kind TDR Failure (atikmpag.sys). Finally I reinstalled the windows but still it does not boot. Does anyone know the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to tackle this if you cannot boot at all, so this is really just a placeholder, too much for a comment, not enough for an answer...

There are no Windows 10 drivers for that computer. Last was 15.7.1 [plus a beta you should ignore] https://www.amd.com/en/support/apu/amd-e-series-processors/amd-e2-series-apu-for-laptops/e2-2000-radeon-hd-7340

Try clean installing the 15.7.1 [you can find clean install in the Advanced mode in the installer].

SoftwareKeep has a slew of things to try, but all rely on being able to boot, so this just for info… [How to fix Video TDR Failure (atikmpag.sys)](https://softwarekeep.com/help-center/how-to-fix-video-tdr-failure-atikmpagsys)